# How to delay a curl request in PHP if my content in foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am using a php script, where I want to send a sms through the api with cURL, but if my phone no is multiple (it is in an array) and I used the foreach to send the sms for every contact no, but when I use cURL request in foreach then it is taking only first contact no, and after that it is not able to send the sms to another no which is available into my contact array.

Here is the code to understand.

```
function sendSMS($data){
    $phones = $data['recipient_contact'];
    $explode_contact = explode(",", $phones);
    //read all the contact and send the mail
    foreach($explode_contact as $k=>$v){
        $contact_number = '91'.$v;
        $sms_body = $data['sms_body'];
        $curl  = curl_init();
        $data = array(
            'aid'=>'XXXX',
            'pin'=>'XXXX',
            'mnumber'=>$contact_number,
            'message'=>$sms_body,
            'singnature'=>'XXXXX');
        $url = sprintf("%s%s","http://mysmslink/HttpLink",http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        sleep(5);
        curl_close($curl);
    }
    return "SMS Send Successfully";
}
```

Comment: Please add the contents of `$result` for a successful and failure pass. I expect you can just `echo` it.

Comment: The answer below suggests that you are hitting the execution timeout. Have you determined that this is actually the case? There is a timeout error message, are you getting that?

Comment: You have misspelled `singnature`, is that also wrong in your real code?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you php.ini set execution timeout in second as your need

```
max_execution_time = 60
```

if you want to define it in php file. Add this line

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);
```

Comment: can we set this in a specific function if we do not want to set at the project level.

Comment: yes indeed. at the below line in your function code
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

Comment: How does your answer help him ? the question was 
"How to delay a curl request in PHP if my content in foreach loop?" , you only help him increase execution time ... not delaying it other than sleep(5);